# Contact form 7, как вставить обработчик?

Tags: wordpress, яндекс-метрика

Как вставить код яндекса в форму contact form 7?
типа такого:

```
onclick="yaCounter123456.reachGoal('zakaz_yslugi'); return true;"
```

Нужно на кнопку input[submit] поставить код метрики
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S.

```
 $('#wpcf7-f46-p1-o2').find('input.wpcf7-submit').on('click', function(e){
     yaCounter12345566.reachGoal('zakaz_yslugi'); return true;
 });
```

Comment: так в контакт форм 7 имеет событие для отправки
Просто вставте в ваш js файл
`document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
   yaCounter123456.reachGoal('zakaz_yslugi');
}, false );`
если вам на подтверждение, а если на клик в форме, то так же в тот js файл просто навешайте событие на клик. https://contactform7.com/tracking-form-submissions-with-google-analytics/

Comment: @Oleksandr, обновил выше вопрос, но данный код не работает

Comment: откуда знаете. Разве ЯМ сразу даные получают?
или вы через console.log() тестили.
Еще 1-о, если реальный проэкт, дайте ссылкочку на страницу с формой, будет просче посмотреть

Comment: @Oleksandr, а подскажите пожалуйста, в вышеприведённого скриншоте где можно вставить код обработчика onclick?